# jquery custom accordion comments section

Tags: jquery

I am building a comments section to a site and am having trouble with a custom accordion effect.

I know this is pretty simple but am having trouble getting it to work.

Here is the code:

```
<li class="main">
      <span class="expand-collapse"></span>

       <ul class="responses">
           <li>
              <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
            </li>
         </ul>
</li>

<li class="main">
      <span class="expand-collapse" href="#"></span>

       <ul class="responses">
           <li>
              <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
            </li>
         </ul>
</li>

$('.expand-collapse').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('minus');
        if( $(this).hasClass('minus') ){
            $(this).find('ul.responses').slideDown(500);
        }else{
            $(this).find('ul.responses').slideUp(500);
        }
    });
```

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
$('.expand-collapse').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('minus');

        $(this).parent().children('ul.responses').slideToggle(500);
]);
```

Any ideas how to get this working. I need to make sure that the accordion is contained so if I click the expand button only the closest thread expands.. not all of them..

Looks like I could be using slideToggle as well.

I have played with closest(), find(), next() all without success..
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Why does your `span` have a `href` attribute? Also please provide jsfiddle example.

Comment: lol... Looks like I left that when going from and anchor to span. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('.expand-collapse').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('minus');
        if( $(this).hasClass('minus') ){
            $(this).parent().children('ul.responses').slideDown(500);
        }else{
            $(this).parent().children('ul.responses').slideUp(500);
        }
    });
```

Try this. I am going form $(this) to the parent and back to the child with the responses class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working rendition of this.
link:: http://jsfiddle.net/mlgmainstream/DTnem/12/

Your Jquery is on the right track.
Comments are on the JSFiddle.

Here is what you do::

```
$(".expand-collapse a").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

//add a open class so user knows which one is opened.
$(this).toggleClass("minus");

//go up a parent dir, then target the "next" element
// which is "ul .responses"
//** this should already be hidden in CSS
$(this).parent().next().slideToggle(500);
```

});

Comment: Notice you only need 2 lines of code, instead of using an "if" and "else" statement.